# Sliding Button Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Last few days i was looking  for a sliding button control for one of my application if any one knows similar thing please pass it over to me

[image]

Comment: One easy way is to use timer to change location or size of your button, but you need to set the timer to do this fast so it can show a better effect. i haven't seen any component that has sliding button in c# winform yet.

Comment: Sliding and all other *animations* are typical things for `wpf` application (as well as shadows and easily achievable glass-effect). In `winforms` animation will be clunky and low-fps. You can easily write custom button and try to use timer to change something and call `Invalidate`. But if you want nice looking UI (like the on on the picture) consider to learn wpf.

Comment: i agree with you Sinatr. if you have some sample code please pass it to me ..